# Sybase load table: custom date format in delimited file

Tags: sap-iq

I need to perform a bulk load in Sybase IQ. The problem is, i have a date format (DD.MM.YYYY) that Sybase doesn't understand out of the box. Now, i can specify the date format in the load table statement, but this makes the field fixed-width, which causes problems because the field can also be empty, in which case Sybase tries to parse subsequent columns into the date.

Data (made up):

```
Foo~12.12.2012~Bar
Bar~.~Foo
```

What i tried:

```
FooField '~',
datefield '~',
BarField '\x0d\x0a'
```

Won't parse the date

```
FooField '~',
datefield date('dd.mm.yyyy') NULLS('.'), FILLER('~'),
BarField '\x0d\x0a'
```

Fails on the NULL

I am hitting granite here, has someone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should have posted the load table statement you tried. In any case, you may have luck using "DELIMITED BY"

```
LOAD TABLE foobar (
    fooField NULLS(BLANKS),
    dateField DATE('DD.MM.YYYY') NULLS(BLANKS, '.'),
    barField NULLS(BLANKS)
)
USING CLIENT FILE '/tmp/fifo'
ESCAPES OFF
FORMAT ascii
DELIMITED BY '~'
ROW DELIMITED BY '
'
;
```

One minor wart for IQ is that you need a delimiter AFTER the final column, and that delimiter MUST be immediately followed by the "ROW DELIMITED BY" character (a newline in my example LOAD TABLE statement).

So, your data file would need to look more like this:

```
Foo~12.12.2012~Bar~
Bar~.~Foo~
```